# Вытащить значение из RoutedEventArgs

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Нужно по нажатию на элемент `ListView` получить сам элемент. Использовать нужно только `ItemClick`, не `SelectedItem` и тд. После нажатия на элемент списка вызывается метод `OnClick`

```
 private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){}
```

В "е" я нашел необходимое мне значение[image: Значение аргумента "е"]

Подвязка события

```
protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.ItemClick += OnClick;
        this.AssociatedObject.IsItemClickEnabled = true;
    }
```

Вопрос заключается в том чтобы его достать, как это можно сделать?

`e.ClickedItem` не находит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.itemfromcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx посмотрите. Это то что вам нужно. Привести пример не могу сейчас

Comment: А что туда нужно передать в качестве параметра?

Comment: OriginalSource, походу. Только надо его привести к DependencyObject

Comment: А ну да... Еще, возможно, тот же элемент находится в sender. Кто вообще генерирует событие? И почему вы не хотите использовать SelectedItem?

Comment: Событие подвязывается в момент нажатия на элемент списка     Добавил в основной пост

Comment: А зачем вам? Есть шанс, что ваша реальная проблема решается по-другому. Какого эффекта вы хотите достигнуть?

Comment: Расскажите подробнее о задаче. Возможно, мы подскажем иные пути решения. Просто с тех пор, как я получил представление о MVVM, у меня отпала необходимость получать объект VM из UI. Скорее всего, вам это тоже не нужно.

Comment: Задача была в том чтобы сделать один метод, который работает со всеми ListView, которые есть в приложении, изначалльно я получал ID элемента и проходил свитчем, но попросили уменьшить код и получить все данные из метода OnClick. Способ товарища Monk работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Приводите `e` к типу `ItemClickEventArgs`, он у вас на скрине.
2. Приводите `e.ClickedItem` (он будет доступен после первого пункта) к `FiltersViewModel`.

Если оба приведения вернули не пустое значение - все ок. Иначе - кто то промахнулся.

В целом, раз уж у вас есть VM, то я бы скорее шел от `SelectedItem` в верхнеуровневой модели, а не от кликов по форме. Это сильно облегчает поведение, когда селект происходит кодом, а не кликом мышью.